# Some thoughts on abstract algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra

$1$ is the neutral element relative to the operation of $\times$ multiplication, since $1\cdot x=x$ for all real $x$. And $0$ is the neutral element relative to the operation of $+$ addition since $x+0=x$ for all real $x$.

And the neutral element of addition when evaluating it with the inverse of  the multiplication operation, is undefined, since $x/0$ is undefined.

Can we extend this idea?

Is there a deep reason in abstract algebra that explains this connection?

Comment: Are you asking for an explanation as to why the neutral element for $+$ happens to be the uninvertible element for $\times$?

Comment: @JackM Yes purely in terms of abstract algebra.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, the objects you seem to be getting at are called (unital, non-zero) rings.  See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_%28mathematics%29) for more information about them.

Comment: Excluding the one element ring, where $\,0$ *is* invertible, so $\,x/0$ *is* defined.

Comment: Yes, what Bill says is true; since you want $x/0$ to be undefined, we must exclude the zero ring.

Comment: Given the OP knows what "abstract algebra" is, and the words "neutral element", I expect they know what a ring is.

Comment: @JackM I know what measure theory is, and know what a measure is, but that doesn't mean I know anything more than just that.  I found no good reason to assume the OP knew any more than that there are structures out there that exhibited this structure.

Comment: @JackM moreover, if they were aware of rings, then they would already know that division by zero is left undefined.  Doesn't hurt to put an answer that might be helpful, even if it doesn't end up being at all.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if I'd call it deep, but it's a general fact in any structure that satisfies the *ring axioms* that $0\cdot a=0$ for any $a$:

$$ 0 + 0\cdot a = 0 \cdot a = (0+0)\cdot a = 0\cdot a + 0\cdot a $$
Now cancel one of the $0\cdot a$ to get $0 = 0\cdot a$.

Because $0\cdot a$ is always $0$ there can't be any $a$ such that $0a=x$, *unless* $x=0$. Therefore $x/0$ must be undefined at least when $x\ne 0$ -- and $0/0$ is likewise not well defined, because the defining equation $0a=0$ doesn't have a *unique* solution (except in the ring with one element, which is not very interesting).

Comment: you didn't understand what I meant. 
I said that can we extend the idea of neutral elements making some operations undefined to any axiomatic system?

Comment: @user145998: Then I think you need to explain better what it is you're asking.